# Maxima exported file in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I exported this document from [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/).

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Created with wxMaxima 12.01.0

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\definecolor{labelcolor}{RGB}{100,0,0}

\begin{document}


\noindent
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{8ex}{\color{red}\bf
\begin{verbatim}
(%i6) 
\end{verbatim}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}{\color{blue}
\begin{verbatim}
VA4: matrix(
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,V,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,V,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,V,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,V,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
);
\end{verbatim}}
\end{minipage}
%%% OUTPUT:
\begin{math}\displaystyle
\parbox{8ex}{\color{labelcolor}(\%o6) }
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{math}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

The above code gives me this output. You can see that after 10-th column it starts new row. I wonder how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increase the value for `MaxMatrixCols` (the default value is 10 and you are using more columns):

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Created with wxMaxima 12.01.0

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\definecolor{labelcolor}{RGB}{100,0,0}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}


\noindent
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{8ex}{\color{red}\bf
\begin{verbatim}
(%i6) 
\end{verbatim}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}{\color{blue}
\begin{verbatim}
VA4: matrix(
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,V,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,V,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,V,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,V,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
);
\end{verbatim}}
\end{minipage}
%%% OUTPUT:
\begin{math}\displaystyle
\parbox{8ex}{\color{labelcolor}(\%o6) }
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & V & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{math}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image]